# Mongoose how to implement nested queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My db schema is

Collection - Question

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("588f79d7535415ceb7a026bd"),
        "type" : 1,
        "question" : "Who is the best bastman from the following:",
        "options" : [ 
            "Sachin Tendulkar", 
            "Rahul Dravid"
        ]
    }
```

Collection - Answers

```
{
    "questionId" : "588f79d7535415ceb7a026bd",
    "answers" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : [ 
                102, 
                101, 
                105
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I created an API to get all the **Questions** and for each "_Id" i need to access the collection- **Answers** and retrieve the answer corresponding to that questionId. **How can i achieve this?** .

Comment: Can you please explain your schema of **Answer's** Collection in more detail? What does this `count: 3` and `count : 6` signify? I would recommend you to embed the answers in **Question's** collections, but before that, I would like to know more about the relationship between Questions and Answers.

Comment: @TarushArora There is no significance of count here, both collections are related only through questionId.

Comment: and what about the userId field inside the answers? Does userId signify that which users have given the answers?

Comment: @TarushArora yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to embed the answer in the question collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588f79d7535415ceb7a026bd"),
    "type" : 1, 
    "question" : "Who is the best bastman from the following:",
    "options" : [ 
        "Sachin Tendulkar", 
        "Rahul Dravid"
    ],
    "answers": [{
         "userId":[102,101,105]             
     }]
}
```

Schema:-

```
{
    "type" : Number, 
    "question" : String,
    "options" : [String],
    "answers": [{
         "userId":[Number]             
     }]
}
```

Or:-

if only `userIds` will be added in future to the `answers`, then you can make `answers` an `Object` instead of an array of objects, that depends on your application logic.

```
{
    "type" : Number, 
    "question" : String,
    "options" : [String],
    "answers": {
         "userId":[Number]             
     }
}
```

Now you do not need to run two queries for retrieving both `questions` and `answers` for a particular question. 
If you need to retrieve data in custom format, you have to use [MongoDB Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

If you want to know more about the embedded data model design in MongoDB, please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/)